How to scan to single input element instead of the two
In my HTML file is use onscan.js. My problem is that  if i select an input field  the scanner writes to that input (cardnameinput) and (cardidinput)  instead of only (cardidinput). If i deselect everything the scanner inputs in the right field. No mater where the focus is i only want to scan to (cardidinput)


$(document).ready(function () {
  onScan.attachTo(document, {
      onScan: function (sCode, oEvent) {
          // Save current focus
          var currentFocus = document.activeElement;

          // Temporarily disable all input fields except #cardidinput
          $("input").not("#cardidinput").prop("disabled", true);

          // Set focus to #cardidinput and insert scanned code
          $("#cardidinput").focus().val(sCode);

          console.log("Card successfully scanned " + sCode);

          // Restore original focus and re-enable all input fields
          if (currentFocus && currentFocus !== document.body) {
              currentFocus.focus();
          }
          $("input").not("#cardidinput").prop("disabled", false);
      },
      onScanError: function (oEvent) {
          console.log("Error reading card");
      },
      suffixKeyCodes: [13], // Enter key ends the scan
      avgTimeByChar: 45,
      minLength: 4
  });
});

function simulate(){
  onScan.simulate(document, '1234567890123');
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;  
}

input{
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onscan.js@1.5.2/onscan.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="cardnameinput" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" >
<input type="text" id="cardidinput" class="k-textbox k-state-disabled" style="width:  100%;" >

<button type="button" onclick="simulate()">simulate</button>




Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

https://github.com/iuyes/jQuery-Scanner-Detection has had its last commits 11 years ago, and the fork https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery-Scanner-Detection 9 years ago. Unless you are using some other fork that is more up to date, you should probably follow the recommendation given in the readme of the latter: "UNMAINTAINED: this plugin is not maintained anymore! Use onScan.js instead - a completely rewritten vanilla JS library with enhanced functionality, support for latest mobile devices, paste-mode scanners and more."

I cahnged to onscan.js

I will be blasted for doing that.. anyway I made a working snippet out of your code changing the bare minimum (mostly adding the required assets) and as you can see the scenario you are talking about is far from happening.. or maybe please explain better.. because yes if you write something in the first input, it gets mirrored on the second one

maybe add this style rule #cardnameinput{ pointer-events: none; } to avoid any drawback like that.. but from your code isn't clear what that input is aimed for so maybe that's not a scenario you can apply

or instead of attaching onScan on the whole document, just do it on the target element you are willing to output the result of the scan.. so something like const inp = document.getElementById('cardidinput'); onScan.attachTo(inp, [...]

one last comment.. if your intention was instead to write the scan inside any selected input being on the page, maybe you should everytime the focus changes, detach and reattach the onScan object to the currently focused input. But this point isn't very clear.. because it was pointed out in the title of the question by a third user  while the body of the question doesn't strictly address that scenario

in the snippet i i click input 1 and scan i get data in both input, i only want in number 2

did you try to do like I said before, by calling onScan.attachTo over the $('#cardidinput')[0] element only instead of the whole document? I ask you because otherwise I cannot test it by myself since the simulate function requires a target and it cannot be different by the target formerly used for attaching the scanner. So I still don't know if it will work even if the focus is on a different element. If it doesn't work, I'm afraid you'd need convoluted ways to circumvent the problem.. ways that could be easily prevented by just arranging things differently

but in general you have an input device that is sending its data to the focused input element.. so it's a weird scenario to select an input control and expecting things to happen elsewhere.. unless you have an global event listener for onkeydown that will fire before anything else and will switch the focus to the #cardidinput automatically.. but yet I think it's not the correct behaviour in terms of accessibility

it is to prevent the user from scanning into the wrong input in a form

yes I understand and I tried ways to get there despite not very cool.. like forwarding the input event fired on any $("input").not("#cardidinput") to $("#cardidinput") but yet weird things happen. IMHO I think the best way is to attach the onscan object to the only allowed element to be filled with the scanner device so that there's no chance of errors but yet the user HAS to select the correct input for it to be filled with the scanned code (unless you have a way to automatically focus the correct element given a signal). This HAS condition it's something I can't check, you had to

with that strategy you don't get false scanned codes in wrong inputs and you have only one element allowed for the scanner to be filled. and yet all the inputs behave normally when typed with normal text
